# SQL Syntax for NOT IN and EXCEPT

Tags: sql

I have a database of genes from different samples and would like SQL commands to retrieve:
1) Genes uniquely obtained from one sample
2) Genes observed in both samples.

The database structure is such that geneids are integers (incremental), for the simple reason that samples may have reoccurring gene names.

I have tried NOT IN and EXCEPT but getting incorrect results. I want to avoid writing java code to specifically achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: "I have tried NOT IN and EXCEPT but getting incorrect results." That's the spot in the question where you usually insert your non-working SQL query.

Comment: Which database system do you use. What is your sql query? What exactly do you want to achive. Can you post an exaple at http://www.sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: You need to supply the table namnes and all relevant field names if you expect an answer. Also, people expect to see the SQL you have tried and what is wrong with the result from that SQL.

Comment: Firstly, 2 tables (samples and genes). Genes from each sample are stored in genes table using: id - Integer, GeneName, ExonCount etc and sampleid as foreign key. Have tired: SELECT GENENAME FROM GENES WHERE SAMPLEID IN ('Male_Brain') EXCEPT SELECT GENENAME FROM GENES WHERE SAMPLEID IN ('Male_Kidney'); Also tried variations of this command using other fields and using NOT IN. Using sqlite and MySQL.

Comment: Except should have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return how many times each genename appears

```
Select GeneName, count(*) from genes group by GeneName;
```